# Kafka consumer not receiving data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am new to Kafka. I have the configuration class below.

```
@Configuration
class factory{ 

 @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        System.out.println("consumer factory created");
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                "http://localhost:9092");
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(
                ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }


@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        System.out.println("concurrent Kafka listener container factory created");
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
      

        return factory;
    }

}

@Service
public class Listener<D extends EventData> {

  @KafkaListener( groupId = "id",topics = "quickstart-events")
  public void listen(String vRecord) {
    System.out.println(vRecord);
  }
}
```

My problem is that when I publish with the kafka-console-producer.sh, my java app is unable to receive anything.

My listener seem to be fine.

It stops immediately.

[image]

Comment: Goes the factory against your local Kafka instance, i.e. bootstrap server? I do not see any configuration regarding this.

Comment: Well, Kafka isn't an HTTP service, so remove the protocol prefix

Comment: Annotate your class `Factory` (please write the first letter of the class name in uppercase) additionally with `@EnableKafka` as it is described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka

Comment: This was originally tagged with `spring-boot`; if this is a boot app, `@EnableKafka` is not needed; Boot automatically adds it if spring-kafka is on the class path.

Comment: Something is closing the application context. Show debug logs and more of your code/configuration. Even better, post a minimal, complete example somewhere so we can see what you are doing wrong.